# Getting "Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30" error when column has NULL value

Tags: c#, odbc, datareader, advantage-database-server

I have a simple .NET console program that uses OdbcDataReader to fetch rows from Advantage Local Server.
I am using System DSN defined via ODBC Administrator on windows 7.
Data Source uses Advantage StreamlineSQL ODBC driver v 10.00.00.03 and following params:

- Database Path:
- Table Type: Advantage Available
- Server Types: Local Server (ALS)

The program works fine until it encounters a row that has a NULL value in the column.
I then get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught   Message=Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 30.   Source=System.Data   StackTrace:
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.Validate(Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.PtrToStringUni(Int32 offset, Int32 length)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)
       at OdbcTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\abcoa\visual studio 2010\Projects\OdbcTest\OdbcTest\Program.cs:line 66   InnerException:
```

Intellisence in VS2010 also gives following hint:
*_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766*

I have also turned on ODBC tracing and can see following error in the SQL.LOG:

```
OdbcTest.vshost b34-11e4    EXIT  SQLSetStmtAttrW  with return
code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        SQLHSTMT            0x0037C6D8
        SQLINTEGER                1228 <unknown>
        SQLPOINTER          [Unknown attribute 1228]
        SQLINTEGER                  -5 

        DIAG [HY092] [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage ODBC
Driver]Invalid attribute identifier. (2184) 

OdbcTest.vshost b34-11e4    ENTER SQLGetDiagFieldW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 
        SQLHANDLE           0x0037C6D8
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLSMALLINT                  4 
        SQLPOINTER         0x05ABE480
        SQLSMALLINT                 12 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x05ABE548
```

If anyone can help with this I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: You are calling `IsDBNull()` and it throws an exception when the column actually is `NULL`?

Comment: @Pieter Correct! I even tried just simple assignment (var obj = reader[colIdx];) and it throws exception at that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Sybase's Advantage.ODBC newsgroup it was suggested that this may be a bug that was fixed in a new upcoming release. I was also able to get new version of the driver by contacting Sybase at advantage@sybase.com and asking them for 10.0.0.5 version of the ODBC 
driver.